# Regular expression format with six numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

```
I have this regular expression

 `NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.?\\,?([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";`

 but i need a limit to 6 number before the dot or the comma and permit always two decimals.
```

Each caracters is checked with regular expression if it is valid i can write.

The problem is that i can write XXXXXXXX (8 numbers) but not six numbers or (XXXXXX.XX) (8 numbers and 2 decimals) for example with this expression

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == _priceTf)
    {
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]{1,6})?(\\.?\\,?([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";

        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                               options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                 error:nil];
        NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                            options:0
                                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
        if (numberOfMatches == 0)
            return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT:**
But if you want validating for example "666.66". First validate "6" and then "66" and then "666" and then "666." and all the time the same and all of them can be valid in the regular expression. This is because i have "?" in all regular expression

But I also have allow writing .666 for example

Comment: ...and what makes you paralyzed to add the missing `{1,6}` or `{6}` to your regular expression?

Comment: This question seems to lack the most basic googling skill, I feel offended by it.

Comment: If i use @"^([0-9]{1,6}+)?(\\.?\\,?([0-9]{1,2})?)?$" the expression permit 8 numbers for example but not decimals

Comment: You realise that your regular expression allows *both* a dot and comma, right?

Comment: Yes, its neccessary dot and comma because is a currency formatt in textfield

Comment: No, like it allows them both *at the same time*. Like `24.,55`.

Comment: Not with Decimal Pad. This problem is solved with this

Comment: The problem is write XXXXXX or XXXXXX.XX. Two lenght can be permite

Comment: @Bosspopuli Don't ever rely on the keyboard for proper key filtering. Users can use external keyboards or paste in text.

Comment: @rmaddy the application it´s only for iphone. Allways show the decimal pad and always have point or dot and if you past the value the expression should block this text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2**: For incremental validity checking on text entry, this should suffice:

```
NSString *expression = @"^[0-9]{0,6}([.,][0-9]{0,2})?$";
```

It matches all strings such that:

- The string begins with zero to six digits.
- The string may have an optional decimal portion.
- The decimal portion begins with a separator (either `.` or `,`).
- The decimal portion is at most two digits long.
- The entire length of the string is processed and there are no additional characters outside of the previous rules.

---

**Edit**: Look, I just don't understand your question. I'm leaving this answer here because it might help you get to where you want to go, even if I don't know where that is.

---

It sounds like you want to restrict the matched strings to only ever contain 6 digits, which must include at least two decimal digits. This means you can have at most 4 digits to the left of the point.

You'll want a regular expression that matches a string for each of these conditions:

```
[.,][0-9]{2,6}         // 0 digits left of point
[0-9][.,][0-9]{2,5}    // 1 digits left of point
[0-9]{2}[.,][0-9]{2,4} // 2 digits left of point
[0-9]{3}[.,][0-9]{2,3} // 3 digits left of point
[0-9]{4}[.,][0-9]{2}   // 4 digits left of point
```

Because total string length is not something that is matched by regular expressions, you can't make the length of the right side *dependent* on the length of the left side. You can combine all of these into one regex if you really want, though.

```
NSString *expression = @"^([.,][0-9]{2,6})|([0-9][.,][0-9]{2,5})|([0-9]{2}[.,][0-9]{2,4})|([0-9]{3}[.,][0-9]{2,3})|([0-9]{4}[.,][0-9]{2})$";
```

I think you'd be better off with this, though:

```
NSString *expression = @"^[0-9]*[.,][0-9]{2,6}";
```

and then just check the length of the string before comparison to make sure it isn't bigger than `7`.

Comment: Additionaly to Ian answer. The regex can be shortened a little by changing  from `[0-9]` to `\d`

Comment: I do not analyze the entire string at a time. Each number has to be valid in the regular expression. thats the problem thats don´t work this regular expression

Comment: If you aren't validating the entire string, you definitely should not be using `^` and `$`.

Comment: But if you want validating for example "666.66". First validate "6" and then "66" and then "666" and then "666." and all the time the same and all of them can be valid in the regular expression. This is because i have "?" in all regular expression

Comment: That´s great!! It´s perfect now!

Answer (score 0):

In Regex, specify the amount of captures using an interval;
Example: \d{0,4} captures any amount of numeric digits, from 0 to 4 digits.
In your case:

```
NSString *expression = @"^([\\d]{1,6})([.]|[,])([\\d]{2,2})\\$";
```

You need to escape the dollar sign as well.

This is the detailed Regex by [Regex101](https://regex101.com/):

```
^(\d{1,6})([.]|[,])(\d{2,2})\$/
^ assert position at start of the string
1st Capturing group (\d{1,6})
\d{1,6} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {1,6} Between 1 and 6 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
2nd Capturing group ([.]|[,])
1st Alternative: [.]
[.] match a single character present in the list below
. the literal character .
2nd Alternative: [,]
[,] match a single character present in the list below
, the literal character ,
3rd Capturing group (\d{2,2})
\d{2,2} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {2,2} Exactly 2 times
\$ matches the character $ literally
```

If you plan on using Regex often, consider adding Regex101 into your bookmarks, its a really useful tool.

Comment: don´t work.. i can´t write the first character with this expression

Comment: I do not analyze the entire string at a time. Each number has to be valid in the regular expression. thats the problem thats don´t work this regular expression